# Advice Regarding Database Design

Tags: mysql, database-design, architecture

I am working on a poory designed application, so please do not judge me by the work i have been posed. I have `servers` table whose data can be visualised as [image]

and `attributes` table which can be described as

[image]

and `attribute_server` table which can be described as

[image]

Now the question and scenario is what to do if the attribute has multiple types meaning, meaning a disk has its own set of types per server, and as well a cpu has multiple set of types per server, and as well multiple set of critical and warning threshold per disk attribute, per memory attribute, per cpu attribute, any idea fellas?

Comment: If you must stay with the schema, could you add more unique attributes? Is each supposed to map to a perfmon counter?

Comment: sorry about the less knowledge but what is perfmon counter?

Comment: Sorry, [Windows Performance Monitor](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/73c5beb7-c499-4551-902d-c351e4f0e88d/list-of-perfmon-counters-for-sql-server) (or the Resource Monitor too). That isn't really relevant unless these are actual recordings from those tools. But the concept is the same. My point was, to make the more unique attributes so that you can distinguish between your data points.

Comment: Your `attribute_server` table has room for multiple disks per server.  (So, I don't understand what the problem is.)